# Must the electrical lights be dimmed or turned off while saying "Borei Me'orei Ha'Esh"?

Tags: halacha, blessing, havdalah

As a follow up to an answer given in [Havdalah and fingers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43523/havdalah-and-fingers) which says:

> The Mishnah in Berachos 51b writes that one should not make the
>   blessing of "Bore Moerei Ha'esh" should only be made if one benefits
>   from the light of the candle.

My question is - Must one turn off dim all electrical lights in the room in order to receive the proper benefit from the candle light, only? In my shul, they do this. But I haven't seen this done too often in most shuls or in people's homes.

Comment: FWIW, we've always done that in my home.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53360/759

Comment: hmmm https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%97_%D7%99%D7%90

Answer (score 5):

Rav Eliyashiv psak is quoted in Ashrei Haish Perek 13:10(pg. 135) saying that one does not need to close the electric by the bracha of aish,and this is what he did in his own home.

Comment: "this" = "close the electric", or "this" = "rely on the not needing to close the electric"?

Comment: Does he give a reasoning?